# How should I represent database tuples in java objects?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, entity, persistence

I'm supposedly writing some code to read and write data from an oracle database. The IO is handled with sql but the problem is in the java classes that store the data from every tuple.

By now I've written a parent abstract class to represent any tuple from any table. Then I got to writing every class for every single table. It's tedious and I'm sure there is a much more clever way of doing this. Every class is basically the same but has different attributes with different names and it's very easy to make mistakes in changing them.

The parent class goes like this:

```
public abstract class DBEntity {

  String entName;
  String key;
  String insertFormat;
  String values;
  boolean isSet;

  public boolean addTo(OracleHelper db) {
    return db.sentence(insertValues());
  }

  public abstract String insertValues();

  public boolean add(OracleHelper db) {
    return db.sentence(insertValues());
  }

  public String find(OracleHelper db, String key) {
    return db.query("select * from " + entName + "where " + this.key + " = " + key);
  }

  public String[] find(OracleHelper db, String value, String attribute) {
    return db.query("select * from " + entName + "where " + attribute + " = " + value).split("\n");
  }

  public abstract DBEntity[] getEntities(OracleHelper db, String value, String attribute) throws IncorrectConstructionValues;
}
```

And child classes are like this:

```
public class Genre extends DBEntity {

  String name;
  String description;

  static String entName = "genre";
  static String insertFormat = "insert into genre(name, description) values('%s', '%s')";
  int PARAM_NUM = 4;

  public Genre(String name, String description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    isSet = true;
  }

  public Genre() {
    isSet = false;
  }

  /**
   * Creates a Game with the first result of the value-attribute combination.
   * If you're sure there is only one possible match use this. Else use another
   * combination.
   *
   * @param db
   * @param attribute
   * @param value
   * @throws IncorrectConstructionValues
   */
  public Genre(OracleHelper db, String attribute, String value) throws IncorrectConstructionValues {

    try {
      String[] params = find(db, attribute, value)[0].split("||");
      name = params[0];
      description = params[1];
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new IncorrectConstructionValues("No hay ningún elemento con esos valores");
    }
    isSet = true;
  }

  public Genre(String allValues) throws IncorrectConstructionValues {


    try {
      String[] params = allValues.split("||");
      name = params[0];
      description = params[1];
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new IncorrectConstructionValues("Algún valor no corresponde" +
          "con el de un atributo para esta clase");
    }
    isSet = true;
  }

  @Override
  public String insertValues() {
    if (isSet) {
      return String.format(insertFormat, name, description);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public DBEntity[] getEntities(OracleHelper db, String value, String attribute) throws IncorrectConstructionValues {
    String[] tuples = find(db, value, attribute);
    Genre[] games = new Genre[tuples.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
      games[i] = new Genre(tuples[i]);
    }
    return games;
  }
}
```

Is there any known better easy way of doing this?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're attempting, but this *looks* like you're trying to reinvent JPA.

Comment: JPA =[Java Persistence API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API) .  Alternatively, don't be so hung up on abstraction and have a look at [JPublisher](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/java.112/e10587/toc.htm)